# onclick automatically fires up when dynamically added with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

The issue I have is I am dynamically populating a div from an API(this API I created on my own) using map. For each attribute (from the API), I am getting an attribute id and dynamically adding it to an onclick. The issue is it automatically fires up by itself but I want it to when when the button is clicked. NOTE. data is gotten from then((data)

The function that populates the div using a map

```
const output = data.map((value) => {
            return `
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="${updateClick(value.id)}" > Edit </button>
                    /
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" role="button" onclick="${deleteClick(value.id)}"> Delete </button>
                </td>
                </tr>
            `;}).join("");
```

The onclick function

```
const updateClick = (id) => {
    console.log("update ", id);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `updateClick()` and `deleteClick()` immediately when you create the template literal. You should put that in the HTML, and use the template to fill in the argument.

```js
const output = data.map((value) => {
  return `
      <button class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="updateClick(${value.id})" > Edit </button>
      /
      <button class="btn btn-danger" role="button" onclick="deleteClick(${value.id})"> Delete </button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  `;
}).join("");
```

Comment: I tried this approach but I got an error Uncaught ReferenceError: updateClick is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Did you define `updateClick`? It needs to be defined in the global scope, not a local function.

Comment: try event.preventDefault();

Comment: @Barmar Yes it is a global scope function

Comment: Then you shouldn't get that error. JS is case-sensitive, so make sure that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above did not help but I found a way to answer this. I added event listeners to every button (Note I added ids for both buttons). You can now add data-id to the button tag to get the exact button clicked if the button tag is dynamically populated.

```
const updateClick = (id) => {
    const edit = document.querySelector("#edit");
    edit.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Edit ", id);
    });
}

const deleteClick = (id) => {
    const del = document.querySelector("#delete");
    del.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Delete ", id);
    });
}
```